# Where is the .zshrc file on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, themes, iterm2

I’m using iTerm and wanted to customize the look of my terminal window using [Oh My ZSH!](http://ohmyz.sh/). And according to the documentation I need to change the `~/.zshrc` file and add a `ZSH_THEME` value:

> Once you find a theme that you want to use, you will need to edit the
>   `~/.zshrc` file. You'll see an environment variable (all caps) in
>   there that looks like:
>
> ```
> ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
> ```

The problem is I don’t know where to find the `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: The tilde (~) refers to your home directory where .zshrc is typically installed and checked for. That's your per-user file that you can create and change to your liking. There's also a global config one in /etc/zshenv, but I wouldn't touch that one.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The `~/.zshrc` doesn’t exist by default in macOS so you need to create it. The `~/` translates to your user’s home directory and the `.zshrc` is the ZSH configuration file itself.

So open up a Terminal — or iTerm — window and create that file like this; I am using [`nano`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nano.1.html) as a text editor but feel free to use whatever text editor you feel comfortable with:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

And then set the `ZSH_THEME` value to whatever value you want to use like this:

```
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
```

Now to save the file in `nano`, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. When it prompts:

> Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?

Type “Y” and then you will get a new prompt which looks something like this; note the path `/Users/giacomo/` will match your local user’s path:

> File Name to Write: /Users/giacomo/.zshrc

Now hit <kbd>return</kbd> and the file will be saved and you will now be back to the command line prompt in the Terminal. If you now exit from the Terminal and then open a new window, the `~/.zshrc` settings should now be loaded in.

Answer (score 36):

The `.zshrc` file is not present by default in macOS Catalina, we need to create it.

Steps for creation:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `touch ~/.zshrc` to create the respective file. (`touch` command will create the `.zshrc` in your current directory but it will be hidden)
3. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>

To view/open `~/.zshrc` you can do either of two things:

1. Open Finder > Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Or:

2. Open Terminal > and type: `open ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 9):

I am using macOS High Sierra, MacBook Pro.

After I installed a Theme, I also needed to change the `ZSH_THEME`.

For me, `~/.zshrc` was already present in my Home directory, but it was Hidden.

I used <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to show the hidden files in Finder, then opened the `~/.zshrc` files with my editor. Updated it and saved it. It worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

"***oh-my-zsh***" now creates `~/.zshrc` automatically now.  Immediately afterwards on my OSX Catalina Macbook I executed:

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

And the file was already there; no manual intervention to create it was required on my part.

And directive `ZSH_THEME` you require was already present:

```
# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Opening iTerm
2. You write `cd` and immediately appear in your account directory to check, write `pwd` (it is very useful to know this command to understand the directory tree).
3. Now write `ls -la` - will display a list of all files (-la will display along with hidden files).
4. Find the .zshrc file. You can read the contents with `cat ~ / .zshrc`. Edit: `vim ~ / .zshrc`. To edit in vim press the `i` button, to save the changes - `esc +: qw`.
5. Done

Useful Links: [Commands in Terminal] (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mac-terminal-commands-cheat-sheet/)
[Getting started with vim] (https://opensource.com/article/19/3/getting-started-vim)